# Help with magento pricing rule

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, rules, shopping, pricing

Hi guys i am having trouble creating a Magento CE price rule.

I have created an attribute called deals. It is a drop down box with these combinations:

2 FOR $100 (MIX N MATCH)

2 FOR $80 (MIX N MATCH)

2 FOR $60 (MIX N MATCH)

I have then applied the attribute to each product accordingly. I have done it this way because our system is also in combination with a barcode printing system and we needed the deal to print on the label too. So i am trying to do a two in one and utilize the same attribute for setting the price rule aswell.

So this is how the rule needs to work:

If a customer purchases one product with the attribute "2 FOR $80 (MIX N MATCH)" then there is no discount.

If the customer purchases 2 products with the attribute "2 FOR $80 (MIX N MATCH)" then it should apply the deal even if its a different product.

If the customer buys 3 products with the attribute "2 FOR $80 (MIX N MATCH)" then the first two products get the deal but the third does not.

This would continue onward with no limit on the amount the customer can buy.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am also a junior developer so take it easy on me guys! haha